Conda cannot find a specific package (Dedalus) in conda-forge that is explicitly listed on conda-forge and active
The package in question is the Dedalus spectral CFD library, here. For posterity I'll also link the project homepage.
When I run conda search --channel conda-forge dedalus or variations with options I cannot find the dedalus package. This isn't a general issue with conda because I can find all default channels packages and every other conda-forge package I tested (most recently related libraries like fipy or gmsh, or general stuff like mamba).
To be absolutely precise, this is what the terminal might look like on my end.
 C:\Users\FirstName LastName>conda search --override-channels --channel conda-forge dedalus
Loading channels: done
No match found for: dedalus. Search: *dedalus*

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - dedalus

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.

I note that pip can locate the associated pypi project, but dedalus is very much a full-stack affair and so is best installed as a conda environment.
I note also that my version of conda is 23.7.4.
I note lastly that when I look for dedalus on an HPC server I SSH'd into I can find it, as one would hope. The server's version of conda is 4.8.3. I'm not sure why there's such a wide version difference, suggesting that maybe I'm on some deprecated system, but my listed build version is newer (3.26.1 vs 3.18.11).
I would appreciate any assistance in troubleshooting this problem. I'm at a complete loss as to what my next steps should be.

Its not available on win64, check the OS tags, which only include

linux-64
osx-64
osx-arm64



Oh wow, I hadn't even thought to check this. Makes sense when you consider that the backend uses an MPI I/O implementation that's presently Linux-only. Much appreciated.
